# Changing Background colour using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change the background color of the page when the model.id is greater then the value 50
so for instance

```
@if(Model.Id > 50)
 {Add this background-color: #CA422B to the style picture class}
```

How can i do this by using jquery

Comment: I don't know the syntax `@if` in jQuery or CSS. I think the question has a tag missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume from the syntax this is Razor in ASP.Net MVC 3? In which case jQuery is not required here as the value is coming from the Model, and thefore not dynamic. HTML and CSS will work fine.

The first thing to do would be to create the CSS classes in your stylesheet which sets the relevant colours:

```
.foo {
    background-color: #CA422B;
}
.bar {
    background-color: #C00;
}
```

Then put the following logic to your view/partial to add the class when needed:

```
<body class="@(Model.Id > 50 ? "foo" : "bar")">
```

The `foo` class with be used where `Id > 50`, otherwise the `bar` class will be.

**Edit**
To add a second class, and give it a value from the model, try this:

```
<div class="@(Model.Id > 7 ? "picture-9999" : "picture-" + Model.Id)">
```

Comment: instead of string.empty , can i use other class , as i have got 2 class with different color , values greater then 50 should have one colour and less then 50 should have white color

Comment: <body class="@(Model.Id > 50 ? "foo" : "foo2")"> .foo2{back...:white}

Comment: i tried this with no success <div class="@(Model.Id > 7 ? "picture-9999" :"picture-@Model.Id")">

Comment: The problem there is the second `@` - see the update in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@if(Model.Id > 50) {
    $('body').css('background-color','#CA422B')
}
```

hope this helps